# Is it possible to toggle or reverse the direction of a css animation?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

As an example, lets say I have a wash that I want to go across a container when a user does something and reverse when they do it again, something like:

```
@keyframes wash{
  0%{clip-path: circle(0% at bottom left);}
  100%{clip-path: circle(150% at bottom left);}
}

@keyframes wash-reverse{
  0%{clip-path: circle(150% at bottom left);}
  1000%{clip-path: circle(0% at bottom left);}
}

.container.opening{
  animation : wash;
}

.container.closing{
  animation : wash-reverse;
}
```

If I want the container to start unaffected by the wash then I want to apply the "wash" to the container (using the opening css class) and then remove it (with the closing css class) is it possible to define a single animation and have a separate CSS rule that says "play the animation backwards"?

I've tried the animation-direction : reverse but I can't get it to work.

A JS fiddle of a working (Chrome only) example where you click on the 'toggle' button to add and remove the wash, completed by defining both animations distinctly, is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/errumm/c7ojz7r6/1/

Comment: Generally, `animation-direction: reverse` should work but the animation in the fiddle itself wasn't working for me and hence wasn't able to test it.

Comment: Perhaps the JS is set up in a way that relies on having two keyframe rules entirely.

Comment: Sorry - only tested the code in Chrome - so if you're not using that it may not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the solution by using translation instead of key-frames.
Config a translation on 'clip-path'. Change the logic of toggle button to add/remove 'in' class.

```
.adl-modal{
 -webkit-clip-path: circle(0 at bottom left);
}

.adl-modal.in{
 -webkit-clip-path: circle(150% at bottom left);
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but the question doest ask for reversed animation. Since the code he posted only was an example